# 'hbase.client.scanner.caching' default value for HBase 0.90.6?

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs, nutch

What is the default value of '**hbase.client.scanner.caching**' for **HBase 0.90.6** version in particular? Is it 1 or 100?

Answer (score 1):

Pretty sure it's 100. The [book](http://hbase.apache.org/book/config.files.html) says so, and 1 would be an odd default for a value defined like this:

*Number of rows that will be fetched when calling next on a scanner if it is not served from (local, client) memory. Higher caching values will enable faster scanners but will eat up more memory and some calls of next may take longer and longer times when the cache is empty.*

Comment: 100 for 0.90.6 version of HBase?

Comment: I looked for documentation of that specific version to link to but couldn't find one. I don't see why they would change the default for that version. And if they did, 1 would be an odd choice.

Comment: Thanks Vidya! What would be an ideal value to set for a 6GB RAM to avoid outofmemory error?

Comment: That depends on your data and what you are doing (such as quantity of reads vs. writes). I say try something ambitious and then bring it down as you test. Trial and error.